# left join with calculated value

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a table 'users' and another table 'positions' with one row for each user stock position (symbol, shares and price). I'd like to know the value of each user's portfolio, which is the sum of their positions (shares * price).

Example:
users table

```
user_id, user_name
1, bob
2, steve
```

positions table

```
position_id, user_id, symbol, shares, price
1, 1, aapl, 100, 119.50
2, 1, ibm, 200, 155.32
3, 2, goog, 100, 660.05
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
user_name, portfolio_value
bob, 43014
steve, 66005
```

(where 43014 = 119.50*100 + 155.32*200)

I'm sure there's a left join that can calculate each position value (shares * price) and then sum them by user with group, but I'm new to mysql. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You seem to have already reasoned out what needs to be queried. Try to write the query out yourself first, or describe what trouble you're having doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing you need is to convert the position to portfolio value. this can be done by:

```
select user_id, sum(shares * price) as portfolio_value
from portfolio
group by user_id
```

and this can be connected to the users table for the name:

```
select user_name, portfolio_value
from users
inner join (
    select user_id, sum(shares * price) as portfolio_value
    from portfolio
    group by user_id
) as values
on users.user_id = values.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Joins (LEFT, RIGHT, INNER) have nothing to do with this. LEFT JOIN in this case means "Give me all rows from table USERS even if they don't have a row in table portfolios". You can read about joins [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). And your query would look like this.

```
SELECT u.user_name, SUM(p.price*p.shares) AS portfolio_value
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN positions p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_name
```